# Static ObservableCollection Event is not firing

Tags: c#, linq, events, observablecollection

I have the following `static` `ObservableCollection` that gets updated using `linq`. Why the event is not firing ?

```
public static class myViewModel
{

    private static ObservableCollection<ObjA> CollectionA = new ObservableCollection<ObjA>();
    private static ObservableCollection<ObjB> CollectionB = new ObservableCollection<ObjB>();

    static myViewModel()
    {
        CollectionA.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(myHandler);
        CollectionA = new ObservableCollection(CollectionB.Select(abc=> new ObjA(abc, True));
    }

    private static void myHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {  
        //To do
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static void updateCollection()
    {

        foreach (var x in CollectionA)
        {
            CollectionA.field=5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not firing because you arent changeing the collection, you aren't even replacing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step one: Give `CollectionA` an event handler.

```
CollectionA.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(myHandler);
```

Step Two: *Discard* `CollectionA` and replace it with a different collection that has no handler.

```
CollectionA = new ObservableCollection(CollectionB.Select(abc=> new ObjA(abc, true));
```

See what you did there?

`CollectionA` returns a reference to a collection object. You aren't adding items to that collection object. You are replacing that collection object with a different collection object.

Add the items to the existing collection instead:

```
CollectionA.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(myHandler);

foreach (var x in CollectionB.Select(abc=> new ObjA(abc, true)))
{
    CollectionA.Add(x);
}
```

If you really want to replace the collection all at once, you need to add the handler to the *new* collection:

```
CollectionA = new ObservableCollection(CollectionB.Select(abc=> new ObjA(abc, true));

CollectionA.CollectionChanged += myHandler;
```

If `myHandler` has the correct parameters and return type, you don't need `new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler`.

The usual way to handle this type of thing is to make `CollectionA` a property which adds the handler itself:

```
private static ObservableCollection<ObjA> _collectionA;
public static ObservableCollection<ObjA> CollectionA {
    get { return _collectionA; }
    set {
        if (_collectionA != value)
        {
            //  Remove handler from old collection, if any
            if (_collectionA != null)
            {
                _collectionA.CollectionChanged -= myHandler;
            }

            _collectionA = value;

            if (_collectionA != null)
            {
                _collectionA.CollectionChanged += myHandler;

                //  Whatever myHandler does on new items, you probably want to do 
                //  that here for each item in the new collection. 
            }
        }
    }
}

static myViewModel()
{
    //  Now, whenever you replace CollectionA, the setter will add the changed 
    //  handler automatically and you don't have to think about it. 
    CollectionA = new ObservableCollection(CollectionB.Select(abc=> new(abc, True));
}
```

## Update

Now, what what *are* we doing with the items? Maybe we want to know when their properties change. `ObservableCollection` won't do that for us, but we can wire it up ourselves.

It's fun to think about ways to refactor this code in a more conveniently reusable way.

```
private static ObservableCollection<ObjA> _collectionA;
public static ObservableCollection<ObjA> CollectionA
{
    get { return _collectionA; }
    set
    {
        if (_collectionA != value)
        {
            //  Remove handler from old collection, if any
            if (_collectionA != null)
            {
                _collectionA.CollectionChanged -= myHandler;
            }

            //  1. Remove property changed handlers from old collection items (if old collection not null) 
            //  2. Add property changed to new collection items (if new collection not null) 
            AddAndRemovePropertyChangedHandlers(_collectionA, value, ObjA_PropertyChanged);

            _collectionA = value;

            if (_collectionA != null)
            {
                _collectionA.CollectionChanged += myHandler;
            }
        }
    }
}

//  NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs gives us non-generic IList rather than IEnumerable
//  but all we're doing is foreach, so make it as general as possible. 
protected static void AddAndRemovePropertyChangedHandlers(
    System.Collections.IEnumerable oldItems, 
    System.Collections.IEnumerable newItems, 
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler)
{
    if (oldItems != null)
    {
        //  Some items may not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. 
        foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged oldItem in oldItems.Cast<Object>()
            .Where(item => item is INotifyPropertyChanged))
        {
            oldItem.PropertyChanged -= handler;
        }
    }

    if (newItems != null)
    {
        foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged newItem in newItems.Cast<Object>()
            .Where(item => item is INotifyPropertyChanged))
        {
            newItem.PropertyChanged += handler;
        }
    }
}

private static void ObjA_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
}

private static void myHandler(object sender, 
    System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //  If e.Action is Reset, you don't get the items that were removed. Oh well. 
    AddAndRemovePropertyChangedHandlers(e.OldItems, e.NewItems, ObjA_PropertyChanged);
}
```

Comment: Yes I meant new ObjA(abc, true)

Comment: before replacing `_collectionA` you should probably do `_collectionA.CollectionChanged -= myHandler;`.

Comment: @Default I didn't want to clutter it up, but... yeah, you're right.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Should the event fires when an item in the observable collection is modified ?

Comment: @John No. Cannot and will not. I'll show what to do if you want that to happen in an update.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Yes. Please! Please note that my ObjA already inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thank you :) Behavior works as expected.